# Project Euler #31 Brute Force

Tags: c++, c, brute-force

In England the currency is made up of pound, £, and pence, p, and there are eight coins in general circulation:

1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, £1 (100p) and £2 (200p).It is possible to make £2 in the following way:

1x£1 + 1x50p + 2x20p + 1x5p + 1x2p + 3x1p

How many different ways can £2 be made using any number of coins?

I saw many solutions for the Project Euler #31 using dynamic programming but only a few people using brute force.

I am trying to make a slow solution for the coin sum problem using an old school brute force. But I am a bit lost.

I have this code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void PrintCombo(int num, int* arr, int index )
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                cout << ',';
            cout << arr[i];
        }
        cout << '\n';
        return;
    }
    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (index == 0 || i <= arr[index - 1])
            arr[index] = i;
        else
            continue;
        PrintCombo(num - i, arr, index + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num = 200;
    int *arr = new int[num];
    PrintCombo(num, arr, 0);
}
```

It is just decreasing by 1 every time. Is it possible to make it to decrease value by 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200 or do I have to write for every coin the same code? I am trying to print every combination which gives 200 and at the end how many combinations give 200 overall.

Comment: You prolly want an array of the coin values, then iterate over it before you enter the function again, i.e. on the line with `num - i`, you would have `num - coins[i]`, where i would go from 0 to the number of coin values, and make sure to check for negative results.

Comment: this has nothing to do with C++ or C. try working it out manually on paper and then formulate an algorithm before jumping into code

Comment: Well the very second line `199,1` is invalid, there's no coin of 199 pence. Perhaps you should ask yourself "1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, these numbers appear in the problem statement, why don't they all appear in my code?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(posting as an answer instead of comment)

You probably want an array of the coin values, then iterate over it before you enter the function again. So you would change the function like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // 8 coin values
{
    if (coins[i] > num)
        continue;
    if (index != 0 && coins[i] > arr[index - 1])
        continue;
    arr[index] = coins[i];
    PrintCombo(num - coins[i], arr, index + 1);
}
```

And have the `coins` array defined somewhere:

```
int coins[] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};
```

Edit: full code with counting instead of listing the combinations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int coins[] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};

int PrintCombo(int num, int* arr, int index){
    if (num == 0)
        return 1;
    int combinations = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ // 8 coin values
        if (coins[i] > num)
            continue;
        if (index != 0 && coins[i] > arr[index - 1])
            continue;
        arr[index] = coins[i];
        combinations += PrintCombo(num - coins[i], arr, index + 1);
    }
    return combinations;
}

int main(){
    int num = 200;
    int *arr = new int[num];
    cout << PrintCombo(num, arr, 0);
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @hvd Yes, didn't actually check it till now.

Comment: The code is working fine, the only problem I faced is how to count the combinations. I tried using a pointer to return a value but when the function is called again at PrintCombo(num - coins[i], arr, index + 1); my pointer is not working for some reason. I also tried to change the function type to int and return an int it does return 0 even though I return a variable (of course I added a code to count the combinations but it still return wrong number (0)).

Comment: @user1947700 You should try to invest some more time into debugging and ask yourself why it doesn't work, see what it returns in trivial cases, etc. Nonetheless, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. When I did see your code I found my error. When I was using a function to return an int, in the code where "if (num == 0)" I was returning 0 instead of 1 so my function was ending.